# Find previous hour and next hour in R

Tags: r, datetime, statistics

Suppose I pass `"2015-01-01 01:50:50"`, then it should return `"2015-01-01 01:00:00"` and `"2015-01-01 02:00:00"`. How to calculate these values in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your time were a variable "X", you can use `round` or `trunc`.

Try:

```
round(X, "hour")
trunc(X, "hour")
```

This would still require some work to determine whether the values had actually been rounded up or down (for `round`). So, If you don't want to have to think about that, you can consider using the "lubridate" package:

```
X <- structure(c(1430050590.96162, 1430052390.96162), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
X
# [1] "2015-04-26 17:46:30 IST" "2015-04-26 18:16:30 IST"

library(lubridate)
ceiling_date(X, "hour")
# [1] "2015-04-26 18:00:00 IST" "2015-04-26 19:00:00 IST"
floor_date(X, "hour")
# [1] "2015-04-26 17:00:00 IST" "2015-04-26 18:00:00 IST"
```

Answer (score 5):

I would go with the following wrapper using base R (you can specify your time zone using the `tz` argument within the `strptime` function)

```
Myfunc <- function(x){x <- strptime(x, format = "%F %H") ; c(x, x + 3600L)} 
Myfunc("2015-01-01 01:50:50")
## [1] "2015-01-01 01:00:00 IST" "2015-01-01 02:00:00 IST"
```

Comment: That works too :-) I would probably recommend using `list` instead of `c` so that when dealing with vectors as the input, it's a little easier to manage. By the way, since when was your timezone IST?

Comment: India Standard Time :)